# Perform operation on grouped columns of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix `M` and vector `G` of integers, such that `G` has as many entries as there are columns in `M`.  For example (schematically):

```
G:     1    1    1    2    2    3    3    3    3

M:     4   20   12    4   71   46   45   25   64
      50   54   88    1   80    8   86   71   26
      28    7   31   44   84   46   35   32    0
      45   15   46   76   39   67   10   59   59
```

The vector `G` encodes a grouping of `M`'s columns.  In the example above, `G` encodes the three groups of columns, corresponding to the three submatrices shown below:

```
  4   20   12
 50   54   88
 28    7   31
 45   15   46

  4   71
  1   80
 44   84
 76   39


 46   45   25   64
  8   86   71   26
 46   35   32    0
 67   10   59   59
```

(NB: for the sake of clarity, in this example I've chosen groups consisting of contiguous columns, but in general, the columns in a group need not be contiguous.  In this case, the ordering of the groups should be the order of first appearance in `G`.)

I want to perform an "collapsing" (or "summarizing") operation on each row of each of these submatrices, and concatenate the resulting columns into a new matrix.  For example, if the collapsing operation is `max`, the procedure just described would generate the three columns shown below to the right of the arrow:

```
  4   20   12           20 
 50   54   88        -> 88 
 28    7   31           31 
 45   15   46           46 

  4   71                71
  1   80             -> 80 
 44   84                84
 76   39                76


 46   45   25   64      64 
  8   86   71   26   -> 86 
 46   35   32    0      46 
 67   10   59   59      67
```

The final result would therefore be the matrix:

```
 20   71   64
 88   80   86
 31   84   46
 46   76   67
```

How does one do this sort of manipulation in R?

---

(FWIW, below is code to create the `M` and `G` shown above.)

```
G <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)

M <- matrix(c( 4, 20, 12,  4, 71, 46, 45, 25, 64,
              50, 54, 88,  1, 80,  8, 86, 71, 26,
              28,  7, 31, 44, 84, 46, 35, 32,  0,
              45, 15, 46, 76, 39, 67, 10, 59, 59),
            nrow = 4,
            byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: You might, also, consider switching to a "data.frame" format -- e.g. having `data.frame(t(M), group = G)` as data, seems convenient to apply any operation by group

Comment: @alexis_laz ; you should put that as an answer

Comment: @user20650 : I guess it -indeed- is on the same track as the answer from thelatemail; just wanted to emphasize the fact that changing the structure upfront might come handy down the road

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi; I think its clarity in producing a dataset in a form that is easy / clear to analyse is worth adding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
## I know your matrix has 4 rows, that is what the `4` in the following means
lst <- split(M, rep(G, each = 4L))
sapply(lst, function (x) sapply(split(x, 1:4), max) )

#   1  2  3
#1 20 71 64
#2 88 80 86
#3 31 84 46
#4 46 76 67
```

The function `function (x) sapply(split(x, 1:4), max)` is really doing row maximum.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option with `rowMaxs`

```
library(matrixStats)
sapply(split.default(as.data.frame(M), G), function(x) rowMaxs(as.matrix(x)))
#     1  2  3
#[1,] 20 71 64
#[2,] 88 80 86
#[3,] 31 84 46
#[4,] 46 76 67
```

Or a variation of the above is

```
sapply(split(t(M), G), function(x) rowMaxs(matrix(x, nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)))
```

Comment: and another variation ... `sapply(split.data.frame(t(M), G), colMaxs)`

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, relying on the fact that matrices are typically filled by column order:

```
simplify2array(by(t(M), G, function(x) sapply(x,max) ))
#    1  2  3
#V1 20 71 64
#V2 88 80 86
#V3 31 84 46
#V4 46 76 67
```